# Como ordernar um dataframe pela ordem de outro?

Tags: r, classificação, dataframe

Tenho 3 dataframes com 2 colunas e 5 linhas cada, da seguinte forma:

Dataframe 1:

```
 estado    casosNovos
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 SP           3189
2 CE           1921
3 AM           1365
4 PA           1135
5 MA            938
```

Gostaria de ordernar o `DF2` e `DF3` pela mesma ordem da coluna "estado" do `DF1`. Tentei utilizar as funções `sort` e `order`, mas os estados acabam ficando em posições diferentes. Por exemplo, ao utilizar a função `order`:

```
DF2 <- DF2[order(DF1$estado),]
```

Resultado:

```
 estado    casosNovos
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 MA            689
2 CE            744
3 SP           3378
4 PA           1285
5 AM           1648
```

Código que estou utilizando:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read_csv("https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19/caso_full/?place_type=state&is_repeated=False&format=csv") %>%
  select(-c(epidemiological_week, order_for_place, city, city_ibge_code, place_type,
            last_available_confirmed_per_100k_inhabitants, last_available_death_rate,
            estimated_population_2019, is_last, is_repeated)) %>%
  arrange(state, date)

names(dados) <- c("data", "estado", "casosAcumulados", "casosNovos", 
                  "obitosAcumulados", "obitosNovos")

DF1 <- dados %>%
  filter(data == max(data)) %>%
  select(estado, casosNovos) %>%
  arrange(desc(casosNovos)) %>%
  head(5L)

DF2 <- dados %>%
  filter(estado %in% DF1$estado, data == max(data) - 1) %>%
  select(estado, casosNovos)

DF3 <- dados %>%
  filter(estado %in% DF1$estado, data == max(data) - 7) %>%
  select(estado, casosNovos)

DF2 <- DF2[order(DF1$estado),]
DF3 <- DF3[order(DF1$estado),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `order` é a própria inversa. Então, se ordenar a ordem de `DF2` pela inversa da ordem de `DF1`, temos `DF2` pela ordem requerida. Complicado? o código é até muito simples.

```
i1 <- order(DF1$estado)
i2 <- order(DF2$estado)
DF2[i2[order(i1)],]
#  estado casosNovos
#3     SP       3378
#2     CE        744
#5     AM       1648
#4     PA       1285
#1     MA        689
```

Se há várias bases a ordenar, o melhor é escrever uma função.

```
ordemEspecial <- function(X, Y, coluna){
  i1 <- order(X[[coluna]])
  i2 <- order(Y[[coluna]])
  Y[i2[order(i1)], ]
}

ordemEspecial(DF1, DF2, 'estado')
```

## Dados

```
DF1 <- read.table(text = "
estado    casosNovos
1 SP           3189
2 CE           1921
3 AM           1365
4 PA           1135
5 MA            938
", header = TRUE)


DF2 <- read.table(text = "
 estado    casosNovos
1 MA            689
2 CE            744
3 SP           3378
4 PA           1285
5 AM           1648
", header = TRUE)
```